# Django testing database is inconsistent with that I can inspect at pgadmin [postgresql]

Tags: python, json, django, postgresql

Using Django 1.4 and PostgreSQL 9.5

I'm migrating my application from sqlite3 to postgresql and I'm having trouble with some fixtures used in the tests.

```
One error that happens many times is:
  File "C:\Users\jackson\Desktop\credit_diagnostic_postgress_env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\loaddata.py", line 196, in handle
    obj.save(using=using)
  File "C:\Users\jackson\Desktop\credit_diagnostic_postgress_env\lib\site-packages\django\core\serializers\base.py", line 165, in save
    models.Model.save_base(self.object, using=using, raw=True)
  File "C:\Users\jackson\Desktop\credit_diagnostic_postgress_env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 551, in save_base
    result = manager._insert([self], fields=fields, return_id=update_pk, using=using, raw=raw)
  File "C:\Users\jackson\Desktop\credit_diagnostic_postgress_env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 203, in _insert
    return insert_query(self.model, objs, fields, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\jackson\Desktop\credit_diagnostic_postgress_env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1593, in insert_query
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
  File "C:\Users\jackson\Desktop\credit_diagnostic_postgress_env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 912, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\jackson\Desktop\credit_diagnostic_postgress_env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\postgresql_psycopg2\base.py", line 52, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
IntegrityError: Could not load main.InformacoesExtras(pk=1): duplicate key value violates unique constraint "main_informacoesextras_user_id_key"
DETAIL:  Key (user_id)=(1) already exists.
```

So, digging to find out what is causing this error I compared the test database created by djando and debugging using IPython I see that there are 2 instances of my User class inspecting with IPython but inspecting the test database in pgadmin I can see none object (row) for the same user.

Here is a test example where I'm using IPython code:

```
def test_CreateUser(self):
    """ Teste para criar usuário e checar se ele realmente foi criado"""
    from IPython import embed; embed()

    self.assertEqual(2, User.objects.all().count())

    response = self.csrf_client.get('/permissoes/auth/user/add/')

    post_request1 = {u'username': 'level1_user1',
                   u'password1': 'senha_239',
                   u'password2': 'senha_239',
                   u'csrfmiddlewaretoken': response.cookies['csrftoken'].value,
                    'profile-TOTAL_FORMS': '1',
                    'profile-INITIAL_FORMS': '0',
                    'profile-MAX_NUM_FORMS': '1',
                    'profile-0-max_num_rodadas': 1}

    response = self.csrf_client.post('/permissoes/auth/user/add/', post_request1)

    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 302)

    self.assertEqual(3, User.objects.all().count())


IPython 4.0.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.
User.objects.all()
Out[1]: [<User: level1_user>, <User: admin>]
```

[pgAdmin database screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VX3Kb.png)
[image]

Any help with this will be awesome.
Thanks in advance =D

Comment: How are you using the test database in IPython? When you do `manage.py shell` you get the normal db, not the test one.

Comment: Hi, Daniel. I edited the example, so you can see how I'm inspecting code during test using IPython. Thanks!